# Is there a way to update the file and not get duplicate values?

Tags: python, csv, file-handling

I am scraping a website using python and getting all the data to a .csv file. (As you can see my code below)
The website keeps updating every hour and so I want to update the already existing file (which has 100 and more pages) with new updated entries on the first few pages of the website. The best way to check that might be detecting duplicate entry using date&time field. What will be a way to do that? I have been trying to figure it out but have been unsuccessful.

1 Append mode to run code for the first few pages and delete entries using excel? (That will be weird here)

2 Pandas has a drop-duplicate option but again, I am confused what to do now that i've come here so far with this

```
import csv
import re
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



params = {
    "action": "livewire_load_posts",
    "school": "",
    "round": "",
    "status": "",
    "orderby": "",
    "paged": "",
}

file = open('output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file) 
writer.writerow(['Date&Time','Status','School'])

for page in range(1, 10):
    
    print("Getting page {}..".format(page))

    params["paged"] = page
    data = requests.post(url, data=params).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["markup"], "html.parser")

    for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):
        
        datime = entry.select_one(".adate")
        status = entry.select_one(".status")
        name = status.find_next("strong")


        datime = datime.get_text(strip=True)
        datime = datetime.datetime.strptime(datime, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
        
        print(
            "{:<25} {:<25} {}".format(
                
                status.get_text(strip=True),
                name.get_text(strip=True),
                datime
            )
        )

        

        writer.writerow([datime, status.get_text(strip=True), name.get_text(strip=True)]
        

    print("-" * 80) 

file.close()
```

Comment: Better to store it in a database (sqlite or postgres or anything) and keep `unique` attribute in whichever column you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the existing csv file and store 'status' and 'school' values in two lists (to create first), then check new values against them and break from the for loops if found, something like this:

```py
for page in range(1, 10):
    ...    
    for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):
        datime = entry.select_one(".adate")
        status = entry.select_one(".status")
        name = status.find_next("strong")

        if status in status_list and name in name_lists:
            break
        ...
```

Alternatively, once you have appended new rows to the csv file and closed it, you could [open it](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in Pandas, [drop duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) rows and save it [back to a csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first", subset=['Status', 'School'])
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Agreed, but I am thinking of keeping that as the very last option here. I am thinking of something which can check with the datetime and update the entries in the csv file. The moment it matches the datetime, it quits the code!

Comment: See my updated answer for additional suggestions.

Comment: One question - How do I compare the date value. Because it works as a 'unique' entry here.

Comment: In that case, you could extend the logic: add a third list of `datime` values to check against in the `if` statement and remove `subset=[...]` in `drop_duplicates` method.

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't able to understand well. Last question, what do you think is the most efficient/feasible option here?

Comment: I would keep it simple and use Pandas. Good luck.